# $\left[A, e^{\lambda B}\right]=\lambda e^{\lambda B}[A, B]$ proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, operator-algebras

In a derivation, my professor used the following property:
$$\left[A, e^{\lambda B}\right]=\lambda e^{\lambda B}[A, B]$$
Where $A$ and $B$ are operators that commute with their commutator $[B,[A,B]]=[A,[A,B]]=0$. How can this be proven?

Comment: Just so I understand fully, do you mean $A$ and $B$ commute with the commutator or if $B[A,B] = 0$ and $A[A,B] = 0$? Or both? (Maybe they're equivalent?)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the post. Yes, they commute with the commutator.

Comment: I think you need to write $e^{\lambda B}$ in a power series.

Comment: Yes, I could write $\left[A, e^{\lambda B}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k !}\left[A, B^{k}\right]$ but then I don't know where to go on from there.

Comment: Prove $[A,B^k]=kB^{k-1}[A,B]$ (for example by induction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to prove that, [in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map), the adjoint action [is but](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_identity)
$$
e^{-\lambda B} A e^{-\lambda B}= A -\lambda [B,A]+ {\lambda^2\over 2!} [B,[B,A]]+ ...
$$
But, in your case, the series truncates after the leading two terms.

It is then evident that
$$
[A,e^{\lambda B}] =  e^{\lambda B} ( e^{-\lambda B} A e^{\lambda B} -A)=- e^{\lambda B} \lambda [B,A]. 
$$

Comment: So simple, thank you!